# I want to remove XSL whitespace from Markdown formatting

Tags: symphony-cms, removing-whitespace

Markdown formatting is coming into my XSL and maintaining its whitespace and breaks. I want it to be converted to actual HTML elements to remove all whitespace.

Here's a look at the [incoming data & HTML source](http://see.weareinto.com/3jwY), and here's the code used to process it..

```
<xsl:value-of select="description-continued" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

The XSL output method already contains `indent="no"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(description-continued)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**You may just need** (in case no group of whitespace characters really matters):

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: you got me 90% there - - SOLVED!

Comment: @Kirk-Strobeck: I am glad that my answer has been useful. Here at SO the expected way of expressing gratitude is by accepting an answer. To do so, one needs just to click on the green check-mark placed next to the answer. :)

Comment: @DM Right, yours is great, but mine is more accurate for the archives. If you want to write the same answer as mine, I can "check" yours.

Comment: @Kirk-Strobeck: Then accept your own answer ... Do you realize how ridiculous to answer one own's question after modifying it and to claim that this is the answer? :)

Comment: @dm umm you really think the modification changed the question? I was just adding some context. Not sure why you thought that last comment was necessary..

Comment: @Kirk-Strobeck: I understand that you are new to SO. Also, I am not interested in teaching you ethics. Based on your behavior I will not answer any your questions in the future and I will also warn other friends about you.

Comment: @dm I returned the question to its original, I thought that's what you wanted. what do you want? not sure why you have a vendetta :\

Comment: @Kirk-Strobeck: Oh man, obviously you are new at SO. Here when you ask a question and get a useful answer, the way to express your gratitude is to accept the answer (by clicking on the green check-mark) and/or to upvote it (by clicking on the up-arrow sign). These actions give the person who answered the question certain amount of rep points (10 for upvote and 15 for acceptance). You still haven't accumulated enough rep points to be permitted to upvote, but you can accept an answer. Sorry, I thought that you knew these rules (who doesn't know them) and thought your behavior was intentional.

Comment: @Kirk-Strobeck:  Anyway, you are *not* required to upvote or accept any answer, but then very soon you will become infamous for this (even if I ignore this behavior, others will not). I can surely live without these 15 points, but not having them for an answer that you said "was 90% of what you needed" -- this feels unfair.

Comment: This isnt used in my code <xsl:template match="text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template> please copy and paste my answer since you want the points. It doesn't make sense to say that's the answer if it isn't :\